# How to apply Conditional Formatting with only one icon showing next to the highest value in a range of cells?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, excel-2016

I am using `Excel 2016` and I need to apply a conditional formatting that will highlight (with a Green circle) the cell with the highest value from a a range of cells.
Say, I have values in Cell `A1`, `B1` and `C1` as shown below:

```
         A    B    C
 Row 1   50   60   55
```

I need a conditional formatting that would put a green circle next to the value in the cell B1 since it is the highest value in the range of cells `A1:C1`

How can achieve this (without using `VBA`)?

Comment: The easiest way would be if you're okay with the circle being *above or below* the largest value instead of *on* it, because then you wouldn't need conditional formatting either.  =IF(A1=MAX($A$1:$C$1),"","")‎

Comment: It's the first time I see a circle in a formula!. Also, Excel does not accept it as a formula. Can you elaborate on your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new custom conditional formatting from the Home menu, by selecting your range (ensure that the active cell--the one lighter-coloured-- is B2), clicking on 'Conditional Formatting' menu and clicking on "New Rule...".

Select "Icon Sets", set the yellow and orange icons to "No Cell Icon" and enter the formula as depicted below:

[image]

Result:

[image]

The formula is:

```
=max($B$2:$D$2)
```

If you have many rows and you need to add the icon to one item in each row, then after selecting the whole table, you will have to use this formula:

```
=max($B2:$D2)
```

(which will adapt the row number to the conditional formatting)